# Why does it matter that you can replace partial derivatives with covariant derives in torsion free connection cases?

Tags: general-relativity

I came across a problem in *Guidry* that asks to prove that if a manifold has a torsion-free connection, the lie derivative is unchanged by replacing all partials with covariant derivatives.

I did the proof, but I want to know why this fact matters and why it is useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Torsion-free* means that at any given point you can find a frame in which all the connection coefficients are zero there.   Now the Lie derivative involves ordinary derivatives and in the frame where $\Gamma^\alpha_{\beta\mu}=0$ at a point  you can replace the ordinary $\partial_\mu$ derivatives by covariant $\nabla_\mu$ without changing anything --- so the two expressions coincide in that frame. But the  Lie derivative with $\partial_\mu$ and the expression with $\partial_\mu\to \nabla_\mu$ are both tensors of the same type, and if two tensors of the same type coincide in one frame they coincide in all frames. So the replacement of $\partial_\mu$ by $\nabla_\mu$ is valid in all frames.

As to utility: the fact that the Lie derivative of the metric wrt to a displacement $\eta$ can be written as $$({\mathcal L}_\eta g)_{\mu\nu}\equiv  \eta^\lambda \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}+ g_{\lambda \nu} \partial_\mu \eta^\lambda+ g_{ \mu\lambda } \partial_\nu \eta^\lambda\\=\nabla_\mu\eta_\nu +\nabla_\nu \eta_\mu
$$
is what gives us the covariant conservation of energy momentum
$$
\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0.
$$

Comment: sorry, im not seeing how this answers the question of why we would want to make this transformation. your answer seems to just reinforce that we can do this. maybe I am missing the point?

Comment: Added a bit abou this.